# Spring boot download multiple files

Tags: spring-boot, for-loop

I got this from someone to download single file,

```
@RestController
public class FileDownloadController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> downloadFile() throws IOException
    {
        String filename = "D:/temp/apple.jpg";
        File file = new File(filename);
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition",
                String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", file.getName()));
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");

        ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers)
                .contentLength(file.length())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/txt")).body(resource);

        return responseEntity;
    }
}
```

But my spec is to have it multiple files. So I tried this,

```
@RestController
public class Downloader {
    @Value("#{${downloadFiles}}")
    private String[] dfile;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> downloadFile() throws IOException {
        String filename = dfile;  //this is error
        File file = new File(filename);
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", file.getName()));
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");

        ResponseEntity<Object> responseEntity = ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentLength(file.length())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/txt")).body(resource);

        return responseEntity;
    }
}
```

I put the files in the application.properties,

```
downloadFiles={'D:/temp/apple.jpg','D:/temp/note.txt'}
```

I need to loop on the "public ResponseEntity downloadFile() throws IOException" method base on the dfile?

Answer (score 0):

Got it again from someone,

```
@Controller
public class FileDownloadController {
    String folderPath="/home/demo/Documents/docs/";
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showFiles(Model model) {
        File folder = new File(folderPath);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        model.addAttribute("files", listOfFiles);
        return "showFiles";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/file/{fileName}")
    @ResponseBody
    public void show(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) {

          if (fileName.indexOf(".doc")>-1) response.setContentType("application/msword");
          if (fileName.indexOf(".docx")>-1) response.setContentType("application/msword");
          if (fileName.indexOf(".xls")>-1) response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
          if (fileName.indexOf(".csv")>-1) response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
          if (fileName.indexOf(".ppt")>-1) response.setContentType("application/ppt");
          if (fileName.indexOf(".pdf")>-1) response.setContentType("application/pdf");
          if (fileName.indexOf(".zip")>-1) response.setContentType("application/zip");
          response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +fileName);
          response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
          try {
              BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(folderPath+fileName);
              int len;
              byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
              while((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                  bos.write(buf,0,len);
              }
              bos.close();
              response.flushBuffer();
          }
          catch(IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              
          }
    }

}
```

[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUT9vd-YhQ0)